# I got error when try to union two selects from two differents tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, union

so guys i created a veiw to regroup information from two tables ( there's informations that exist in table A but not in table b and vise verca

```
USE [DATAWARHOUSE]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[GroupingCP]    Script Date: 3/27/2019 10:29:39 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER VIEW [dbo].[GroupingCP] AS

SELECT [CODFILIALE]
      ,[I_CODPRO]
      ,[CODICE]
      ,[RagioneSociale]
      ,[Indirizzo]
      ,[Cap]
      ,[Localita]
      ,[Provincia]
      ,[CodNazione]
      ,[DesNazione]
      ,[Telefono]
      ,[Fax]
      ,[CodiceFiscale]
      ,[PIVA]
      ,Null as [ice]
      ,[CodPagamento]
      ,[ancodval]
      ,[flgsconto]
      ,[CodIvaLDI]
      ,[NumeroLDI]
      ,[AnnoLDI]
      ,[pivastampafattura]
      ,[banca]
      ,[Email]
      ,[afflintr]
      ,[TipoNazione]
      ,[CodFilialePassiva]
      ,[SDI]
      ,[LegalMail]
      ,[FlgAssigne]
      ,[AgentAssigne]
      ,NULL AS [CodNazioneFiliale]
      ,NULL AS [flgbloccofatturazione] 
      ,NULL AS  [DateModif]
      ,NULL AS  [devise]
      ,NULL AS  [exo]
      ,NULL AS  [nexo]
      ,NULL AS [dexo]
      ,NULL AS [dendexo]
       FROM tmp.CLIENTICONTABILI
       WHERE codice NOT IN ('00001247','00001254','00001259')
       UNION 
       SELECT [CODFILIALE]
      ,[I_CODPRO]
      ,[CODICE]
      ,[RagioneSociale]
      ,[Indirizzo]
      ,[Cap]
      ,[Localita]
      ,[Provincia]
      ,[CodNazione]
      ,[DesNazione]
      ,[Telefono]
      ,[Fax]
      ,[CodiceFiscale]
      ,[PIVA]
      ,[ice]
      ,[CodPagamento]
      ,[ancodval]
      ,[flgsconto]
      ,[CodIvaLDI]
      ,[NumeroLDI]
      ,[AnnoLDI]
      ,[pivastampafattura]
      ,[banca]
      ,[Email]
      ,[afflintr]
      ,[TipoNazione]
       [CodFilialePassiva]
      ,NULL AS SDI
      ,NULL AS legalmail
      ,[FlgAssigne]
      ,[AgentAssigne]
     ,[CodNazioneFiliale]
     ,[flgbloccofatturazione]
     ,[DateModif]
     ,[devise]

     ,[exo]
     ,[nexo]
     ,[dexo]
      ,[dendexo] FROM tmp.CLIENTICONTABILIEXT;
GO
```

> Msg 205, Niveau 16, État 1, Procédure GroupingCP, Ligne 5 [Ligne de
>   départ du lot 9] All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or
>   EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their
>   target lists.

Comment: The error message says it all. Add `null` for unmatched columns.

Answer (score 0):

you've to have equal no of columns for selection - in your first selection there is 38 columns where as in your 2nd selection it is 39 - and that's the reason you got error

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, ...coln from tablename1
union all
select col1, col2, col3, col4, ...coln from tablename2
```

Comment: i know, the number are equal and i still got the error

Comment: in your first selection there is 38 columns where as in your 2nd selection it is 39 @yassinemhadhbi

Answer (score 0):

I check your all parameter equal both tables might be please set datatype when applying null values into your column depending on another table like this.

Ex:-

```
 CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) AS ICE
```